# Pandas, find the number of times a combination of rows appear under a different column ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'purchase': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
                   'item': ['apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'apple']})
df

   purchase    item
0         1   apple
1         1  banana
2         2   apple
3         2  banana
4         2   pear
5         3    apple
```

And I need an output such as

| item_1 | item_2 | purchase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | banana | 2 |
| banana | pear | 1 |
| apple | pear | 1 |

A table counting how many times a combination of two fruits was purchased in the same purchase.

In this example's first row, the values are **apple**, **banana**, **2** because there are two purchases (see column **purchase**), purchase ID 1 and purchase ID 2, where the person bought both apple and banana. The second row is **apple**, **pear**, and **1** because there's only one purchase (purchase ID 2) where the person bought both apple and pear.

My code so far:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'purchase': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
                   'item': ['apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'apple']})
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['item'])
df2 = pd.concat([df['purchase'], dummies], axis=1)
```

Creates a table like this:

```
   purchase  apple  banana  pear
0         1      1       0     0
1         1      0       1     0
2         2      1       0     0
3         2      0       1     0
4         2      0       0     1
5         3      1       0     0
```

Now, I don't know how to proceed to get the wanted result (and I'm aware my output is far from the wanted one). I tried some group by's but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the logic behind the values in the `fruit_apple` and `fruit_banana` columns in your output? Why are there multiple `fruit_apple` and `fruit_banana` entries at all if you're trying to find the number of times that combo was purchased? Why aren't there combo amounts for `apple / pear` and `banana / pear` from purchase 2? This post needs a lot more details.

Comment: I've edited the code. I tried to simplify it to remove the unnecessary content.

Comment: But you still haven't explained the logic behind the values in your output table.

Comment: I thought I did where I mentioned "The output is ....a  table counting how many times a combination of two fruits was purchased in the same purchase. In this example, apple and banana appear in two different purchases (purchase 1 and purchase 2), hence the number 2 in the purchases column."

Comment: No, that only explains the values in the "purchase" column. What about the other values? Where does `1, 3` come from under `apple, banana` in the third row? Why is row 3's purchase value the same as row 2's? Your logic isn't at all clear, and judging by the upvotes on my comments in this thread, I'm not alone.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. And yes, you're completely right. I butchered the explanation and the data. I hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most efficient, but it seems to get the job done:

```py
In [3]: from itertools import combinations

In [4]: combos = df.groupby("purchase")["item"].apply(lambda row: list(combinations(row, 2))).explode().value_counts()

In [5]: combos.reset_index()
Out[5]:
             index  item
0  (apple, banana)     2
1    (apple, pear)     1
2   (banana, pear)     1
```

From there,

```py
In [6]: pd.DataFrame([[*x, y] for x, y in zip(combos.index, combos)], columns=["item_1", "item_2", "combo_qty"])
Out[6]:
   item_1  item_2  combo_qty
0   apple  banana          2
1   apple    pear          1
2  banana    pear          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take that uses the behavior of `join` with duplicated index:

```
df2 = df.set_index("purchase")
df2 = df2.join(df2, rsuffix="_other")\
  .groupby(["item", "item_other"])\
  .size().rename("count").reset_index()
result = df2[df2.item < df2.item_other].reset_index(drop=True)

#      item item_other  count
# 0   apple     banana      2
# 1   apple       pear      1
# 2  banana       pear      1
```

I get around 10x speedup over using builtin `combinations` in the following benchmark:

```
import numpy as np

num_orders = 200
max_order_size = 10
num_items = 50

purchases = np.repeat(np.arange(num_orders), 
                      np.random.randint(1, max_order_size, num_orders))
items     = np.random.randint(1, num_items, size=purchases.size)

test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "purchase": purchases,
    "item": items,
})
```